# Solaris: Binary Compatibility of libSTLPort.so with libCstd.so?

Tags: c++, solaris, stlport

I'm trying to connect ro MySQL Server using MySQL Client Library (libmysqlclient.so) from my C++ Program. This libmysqlclient.so on Solaris has a dependency with libstlport.so.

```
 libstlport.so.1 =>       (file not found)
```

This is what I can see with "ldd" command. I read in Oracle docs that inbuilt libCstd.so and libstlport.so are binary-compatible. So Can I copy libCstd.so and rename it to libstlport.so or something like this to make MySQL Client Library to work ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle Solaris Studio 12.2: C++ User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1383/bkakg.html) :

> STLport is binary **incompatible** with the default libCstd. If you use
>   the STLport implementation of the standard library, then you must
>   compile and link all files, including third-party libraries, with the
>   option -library=stlport4. This means, for example, that you cannot use
>   the STLport implementation and the C++ interval math library
>   libCsunimath together. The reason for this is that libCsunimath was
>   compiled with the default library headers, not with STLport.